# Oracle Managed Dataacess EF6 custom edm mappings not applying

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework-6

We have a lot of instances of number(5,0) in our oracle db for which oracle provider defaults to Int16. This causes an issue because we can have a larger value than allowed in the int16 range for the same. Oracle recommends to override the edm mappings with custom mappings (see docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300 ).

The issue I am facing is even with those custom mappings in my asp.net mvc project's web.config the override is not applying. I also created a brand new console app to test this and no luck either.

Does anyone know how to make it work or have a better solution?

### I probably should add this info,

- VS 2015 EF6 Oracle Managed Data Acesss latest version from NuGet
- I am aware the docs say you can manually edit the types in Table Mapping
  but when you try to change them it conflicts with the emd model and
  generates an error.
- Workaround in which you manually edit the xml to
  remove precision is good in short term but every time you have to
  update from DB it overwrites the changes. It's a chore since I have
  more than 40 enteries in some tables to be edited

(below is the entry in web.config/app.config)

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<version number="*">
  <edmMappings>
    <edmMapping dataType="number">
      <add name="bool" precision="1" />
      <add name="byte" precision="3" />
      <add name="int16" precision="4" />
      <add name="int32" precision="9" />
      <add name="int64" precision="18" />
    </edmMapping>
  </edmMappings>
  <dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
  </dataSources>
</version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this helps in your situation,  but with entity framework code first you can use Fluent API to configure properties.  Default Code-First convention creates a column for a property with the same name, order, and datatype. You can override this convention, as shown below.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        //Configure Column
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .Property(p => p.DateOfBirth)
                    .HasColumnName("DoB")
                    .HasColumnOrder(3)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");
  }
```

Additional Resources on Fluent API:

[entityframeworktutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)

[msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to stick forever to EF 6 version? If not, since edmx designer is dropped in 7 version, maybe should your team start getting used to handle mappings by itself instead of letting a designer do the work bluntly.